# Is sales tax charged on checked baggage fees?

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, travel, california, airline

When I buy airplane tickets online, I pay for associated taxes at the same time. But if I have luggage to check, that's a separate cost that gets added when I check in.

Should I expect to pay sales tax on these fees, if I am in a state that charges sales tax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The IRS has ruled that taxes do not have to be paid on checked baggage fees.

http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-wd/1002004.pdf

Also an explanation here.
http://rescommunis.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/guest-blogger-taxes-and-checked-baggage/